# C++ _popen 'UWFmgr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch files

Tags: c++, popen

I am using _popen method to execute the uwfmgr on Windows 10 Enterprise but my progam shows 'UWFmgr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch files, although the UWF feature already installed and uwfmgr is available in C:\Windows\System32.

```
bool Utils::DoesUwfExist()
{
    char psBuffer[128];
    FILE *pPipe;

    printf("Search UWF...");

    if ((pPipe = _popen("UWFmgr volume get-config C:", "rt")) == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        bool ok = false;
        char* okstr = "Protected Volume Configuration";

        while (!feof(pPipe))
        {
            if (fgets(psBuffer, 128, pPipe) != NULL)
            {
                if (ok == false && _mbsnbcmp((const unsigned char*)psBuffer, (const unsigned char*)okstr, 25) == 0)
                    ok = true;
            }

            _pclose(pPipe);

            return ok;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I did check the Environment Variables, the C:\Windows\System32 is set in the Path variable.

However, I am able to execute the uwfmgr from the command prompt as below:
[command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoNla.png)

Any other things I missed? Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the `PATH` used by `_popen` is not what you expect.

Comment: If you know the exact absolute path to the program, why don't you try using that in `popen`?

Comment: @Useless Full path C:\Windows\System32\uwfmgr.exe is also the same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the **PATH** used by **_popen** not suppose should be same as the **PATH** we set at the Environment Variables? How to check the **PATH** used by **_popen**?

Answer (score 0):

The application is a 32-bit application and it is running on Windows 64-bit. Therefore, by default, it will redirect to C:\Windows\SysWOW64. But, the UWF is only available in 64-bit version in C:\Windows\System32. To solve this problem, we have to call the **Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection** function before we execute the UWF and call **Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection** function after the UWF execution.